# How to use Admob in my activity without a xml file

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I created a game only using activities and extending View, the problem is that i dont know how can i setup my Admob in my activity, since if i dont put a layout in my sentContentView it says is null. I already tried creating a layout in the activity and it didnt work, i also tried adding my view in the xml and didnt work either. I dont know how can i solve this problem.
My Menu activity:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Menu menu = new Menu(this);
    menu.setKeepScreenOn(true);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(menu);
    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ad_id_banner");
    mAdView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

My Menu View (i will only put the constructor):

```
public class Menu extends View {

private Bitmap titleGraphic;
private Bitmap playButtonUp;
private Bitmap playButtonDown;
private Bitmap InstruButtonUp;
private Bitmap InstruButtonDown;
private Bitmap background;
private Bitmap back;
private boolean playButtonPressed;
private boolean instruButtonPressed;
private int screenW;
private int screenH;
private Context myContext;

public Menu (Context context){
    super(context);
    myContext = context;
    titleGraphic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.title_graphic);
    playButtonUp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.play_button_up);
    playButtonDown = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.play_button_down);
    InstruButtonUp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.instru_button_up);
    InstruButtonDown = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.instru_button_down);
    back = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(myContext.getResources(),R.drawable.frontbackground);

}
@Override
public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
{
    super.onSizeChanged(w,h,oldw,oldh);
    screenW = w;
    screenH = h;
    background = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(back,screenW,screenH,true);
}
```

Here i created a XML for the AdMob:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.acimutstudios.puzzle.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the logCat error message:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.acimutstudios.puzzle, PID: 6885
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.acimutstudios.puzzle/com.acimutstudios.puzzle.MenuActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest)' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest)' on a null object reference
                  at com.acimutstudios.puzzle.MenuActivity.onCreate(MenuActivity.java:37)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
```

Comment: in onCreate you are calling `setContentView(...)` with the Menu `View` which doesn't load the AdMob layout. Every call to `this.findViewById()` will give you a null reference for mAdView

Comment: Yeah i know that but my Menu View is where my game runs so i need to set the contentView to Menu. How can i set the layout and run my Menu View at the same time?